# How to select which columns are good for visualisation in k-Means clustering algorithm?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, k-means, kaggle

I am trying to understand the selection of columns in csv file which should be taken into considerations to apply k-means .
In the below link only annual income and spending score is taken as a column (from Mall_Customers.csv file)  for visualisation and not age.
https://www.kaggle.com/shrutimechlearn/step-by-step-kmeans-explained-in-detail

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

They have 3 features that they can use to cluster. Usually they will just take the euclidean distance of all the features to get the distance from cluster to cluster.

This is very easy to visualize in two dimensions. Take two points and the distance between them is the hypotenuse of a triangle.  In three dimensions, it's a little harder to visualize. The author is simply using 2 dimensions so she can plot it later. However, to use all three dimensions you would simply modify the code to:

`X = dataset.iloc[:,[1:3]].values`

and that will use age,income and spending score in the algorithm

Comment: So, always we need to focus on choosing 2 columns to visualise the data.

Comment: Generally, you will not visualize clustering on the features that make up your distance if there is more than 3. However, you can do certain tricks like plotting a color and size to visualize a 3rd and 4th dimension. Check out [this seaborn plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatter_bubbles.html) - Also there is a whole discipline of statistics called [dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction#Feature_projection) to be able to visualize multiple dimensions in 3 or less dimensions.